# JSON_QUERY Not Working when JSON key contains Colon

Tags: ansible

### My JSON File

```
{
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "ontap_info": {
            "ontap_version": "160",
            "volume_info": {
                "testvol1:test1": {
                    "encrypt": "false",
                    "encryption_state": "none",
                    "encryption_type": "none",
                    "key_id": null,
                    "volume_antivirus_attributes": {
                        "on_access_policy": "default"
                    },
                },
                "testvol2:test2": {
                    "encrypt": "false",
                    "encryption_state": "none",
                    "encryption_type": "none",
                    "key_id": null,
                    "volume_antivirus_attributes": {
                        "on_access_policy": "default"
                    },
                },        
            },
        },
    },
}
```

### My Task

```
- name: Volume Aggr Info
    raw: |
      VOLUME_NAME="{{ ontap_volume_info | json_query( info ) | json_query( "'item'" ) | json_query( volumename ) }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    loop: "{{ ontap_volume_info.ontap_info.volume_info.keys() | list }}"
```

I have to loop through the key which contains the colon, for example `"testvol2:test2"`.

I tried multiple solutions and nothing is working. When I try to display the `VOLUME_NAME` variable, it is displaying an empty string.

Comment: Fix the JSON and [test](https://jsonformatter.org/) it.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Loop through the key which contains the colon, for example, "testvol2:test2"*

A: Each of the keys must be unique. [YAML places no further restrictions on the nodes](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764044).

Given a **valid** JSON in the variable `my_data`. The task below does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_data.ontap_info.volume_info[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_data.ontap_info.volume_info.keys()|list }}"
```

should give

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=testvol1:test1) => {
    "msg": {
        "encrypt": "false",
        "encryption_state": "none",
        "encryption_type": "none",
        "key_id": null,
        "volume_antivirus_attributes": {
            "on_access_policy": "default"
        }
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=testvol2:test2) => {
    "msg": {
        "encrypt": "false",
        "encryption_state": "none",
        "encryption_type": "none",
        "key_id": null,
        "volume_antivirus_attributes": {
            "on_access_policy": "default"
        }
    }
}
```